# If within a map with arrow syntax

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do an if like below:

```
<tbody>
  {aiData.map((row, index) => (
    if(row[3]==='trace'){
      <tr key={index}>
      <td>{Moment(row[0]).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")}</td>
      <td>{row[3]}</td>
      <td>{row[2]}</td>
      <td>{row[1]}</td>
    </tr>
    }
    else if(row[3]==='trace'){
    }        
  ))}
</tbody>
```

It seems from the thread here it should be possible. But I get following error. I also tried returning the content.

> Parsing error: unexpected token.

If i wrap in braces I get following:
[image]

Comment: why are you checking same condition in if and else part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `xxx(YY) => (ZZ)`, it's the same as `xxx(YY) => (return ZZ)`.

The best way to do what you want is to wrap the `ZZ` with `{}` to transform it as a function with possible instructions :

```js
{
  aiData.map((row, index) => {
      if(row[3]==='trace') {
        return (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{Moment(row[0]).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")}</td>
            <td>{row[3]}</td>
            <td>{row[2]}</td>
            <td>{row[1]}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      } else if(row[3]==='trace') {
        return (null)
      }        
  })
}
```

Comment: which line is responsible of your `Parsing error: unexpected token.` ?

Comment: Se original post. I added picture.

Comment: There is some `{` & `}` missing in your code around the all aiData.map (just edited my answer for you to see)

Comment: Worked. Thanks alot appreciated.